# Doing dhikr in these manner?

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, dhikr

Sometimes I use corn grains or beans as a tool to count dhikr. I know for example:there are 100 corn grains or beans and everytime I say 1 estagfirullah, or 1 la ilahe ilallah i pass 1 corn grain or 1 bean. Is this permissible or it is bid'ah. I know that sahabah used grapes to count dhikr and I also know it's best to use fingers but is it allowed to use other things, like corn grains and beans?